# Scikit-Learn Version Not Updating

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, pip

I am trying to update `scikit-learn` library via `pip`, yet I have not succeded due to error occurences.

I have initially updated it using the command below:

```
sudo pip install -U  scikit-learn
```

Though, it says that:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Which to my concern means that it is the latest version `0.19.0`

But when I check the version directly in Python interpreter, it returns `0.16.1`:

```
>>> import sklearn
>>> print sklearn.__version__
0.16.1
```

How can I update to the latest version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By prepending `sudo` in the `pip` call, you are referring to the system's python instead of a virtualenv one.

If you are within a virtualenv, simply do `pip install -U scikit-learn` (i.e. drop the sudo).

EDIT:
OP installed sklearn with apt, `sudo apt remove --purge python-sklearn` and reinstall sklearn with `pip` solved it.

Comment: I tried without sudo, it gives the same message `Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and also displays version `0.16.1`

Comment: Could you do `python -c 'import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)'` and also `which python` in the terminal please?

Comment: first command gives `0.16.1`, I'm using python version `Python 2.7.10`

Comment: I am trying to confirm that you are using the right python interpreter, `which python` should tell you which python interpreter are you using.

Comment: `➜  ~ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
`

Comment: That still doesn't tell me which python interpreter are you using. Please run the following command `which python` in your terminal. It should say `/usr/bin/python2` or `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: it says `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153970/discussion-between-ryan-tam-and-mandeep-singh).